# Previously drawn images not retained using iOS CGContext

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I am not able to retain previous drawing images in the CGContext:

```
//draw a rectangle      
-(void)drawSquareAndRect:(CGPoint)from endPoint:(CGPoint)to
    {
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor redColor]set];
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);
        float i,j;
        i=to.x;
        j=to.y;
        if (((from.x >= 10.0 && from.y >=10.0) && (to.x <=290 && to.y <= 390)) && ((to.x >= 10.0 && to.y >=10.0) && (from.x <=290 && from.y <= 390)) )
        {
            //[drawImage.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
            CGContextAddRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(from.x,
from.y,i-from.x,j-from.y));
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            self.drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
           CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeHue);
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       }
  }
```

Comment: Am using uiview and drawing image view with image , every time am going  to draw the square or rectangle, i need to get my previous drawing images but it shows only current images only

Comment: i don't get this question I am afraid

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to add cumulative shapes when drawing.  They don't seem to realise that they will to model those shapes and redraw all/some of them when drawing into the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Another Image View Temp and assign draw image view to temp image view then it will saved

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to retain the previously drawn image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
[self.drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.drawImage = image;
```

Try this.